# How Can I write The Following Query In hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
Select * from Table A left join Table B on A.id=B.id and A.langCode='IN';
```

where 'IN' is input from user.

Table A and Table B has Mapping For Id but there is no Mapping with LangCode between the two as table B dosent have an column called langCode to map with , i want to write the following query using hibernate criteria without mapping langcode.

Table: Employee :
EMP_ID - primary key ,
NAME ,
CONTACT_DETAILS

Table:Employee_Lang:
EMP_ID- composite primary key,
LANG_CODE- composite primary key,
NAME

Actual Query:

```
Select * from Employee Emp left outer join Employee_Lang EmpLang on Emp.EMP_ID=EmpLang.EMP_ID AND EmpLang.LANG_CODE='IN'
```

I have mapped only the Emp_Id as primary key from both the tables in hibernate hence hibernate criteria will only apply a join on that 
And not on LangCode.

Note:-I cant change hibernate mapping and can use only hibernate Criteria , as per the clients requirement, please help me on this one.

Comment: Could you add your entities A and B code with fields.

Comment: Hi i have added the changes , could you help me on this

Comment: I meant java classes A and B could you add them?

Comment: Actually this is just a glimpse  of what i want to achieve ,the classes i am working on are completely different from this, i have added this reference data as i cant give the actually classes here (client agreement) hope you understand me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have two models:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @OneToOne
  private EmployeeLang employeeLang;
  ...
}
@Entity
class EmployeeLang {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String langCode;
  @OneToOne
  private Employee employee;
  ...
}
```

You should have some mapping between them and then you can do next criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.createAlias("employeeLang", "empLang"); // inner join with EmployeeLang
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("empLang.langCode", "in");

List<Employee> employees = criteria.list();
```